# Oracle case sensitive Format SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, code-formatting

I need to format SQL statement for Oracle Db. I have a sql statement and I don't want to change the case. For Eg.

```
CREATE TABLE DPAuditTrailDetail
(
   ID               NUMBER (19, 0) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
   AuditTrail       NUMBER (19, 0) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
   sysObjectField   NUMBER (19, 0) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
   OldValue         NCLOB DEFAULT NULL ,
   NewValue         NCLOB DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
   Referenced       NUMBER (19, 0) DEFAULT NULL
);
```

I believe, to create table with this table name and column names in oracle, i will have to add double quotes("") to each name. I have a big script and I would like to do it as quick as possible.

Please do suggest some quick way to do it.

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is not clear as to what you want to do.

Comment: don't do it. First explain to me why you insist on using quoted strings as table/column names.

Comment: The problem with mixed-case identifiers is that some people don't realise they are possible and are easily tripped up when they come across them :)

Comment: Apart from manually adding the double-quotes by hand, your answer will probably be some tricky vi tricks or a cool sql-formatting tool.

Comment: i am using an OR Mapper ,which is generating tables names case sensitive, when it runs it deletes my exported tables and creates new empty tables..i want to keep names same as my OR Mapper.

Comment: Why are you implementing your own audit trail?  Oracle already does what your table definition above appears to be trying to accomplish.
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14266/cfgaudit.htm

Answer (score 2):

Just use the CREATE statement as-is. The tables will be created so that all the following will work just fine:

```
select AuditTrail from DPAuditTrailDetail where ID=1;

select AUDITTRAIL from DPAUDITTRAILDETAIL where ID=1;

select aUdITtraIL from dpaudittraildetaiL where id=1;
```

Oracle queries are case-insensitive by default and your life (and that of those maintaining your code when you're gone) will be easier if you stick to this default.

Comment: @hhk999: This is correct, if you leave out the quotes and the OR mapper tries to execute "DROP TABLE DPAuditTrailDetail" it will succeed.

Answer (score 1):

If you really have to use case-sensitive table/column names, the only way is to add double-quotes to table/column names. But as the commenters said, it's not good practice to use case-sensitive names